# Image select area and rotate with jQuery

Tags: jquery, rotation, crop

I'm looking for best solution in order to select area on image and additional option for rotate this area.

Comment: Would you first like to crop the image and then rotate that cropped part?

Comment: I've seen a captcha like that soemwhere. I cannot find it back

Comment: Maybe I explained bad, in fact I do not need crop images, i want to select area and the ability to rotate that area.